# Some issues in C++ performance measurement

Tags: c++, linux, optimization, profiling, performance-testing

```
 timespec start, end;
 clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
 ---code--lookup in a unordered map <string, int>
 clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);
 int diff = diff_ns(end, start);

Results:
 SAMPLE   MIN(ns)   MAX(ns)   AVG(ns)
           100      1000      3000      1430
           500      1000      2000      1436
          1000         0     16000      1441
          5000         0     15000      1479
         10000         0     26000      1489
         50000         0    363000      1589
        100000         0    110000      1591
        200000         0    804000      1659
        300000         0    118000      1668
        400000      1000    354000      1701
        500000         0   8679000      1712
        600000         0    809000      1701
        700000         0    373000      1704
        800000         0    850000      1716
        900000         0    856000      1736
       1000000         0    817000      1730
```

- How to ignore time spent by CPU to calculate the clock_gettime as in the end we take time spent also by clock_gettime call?
- I am running tests in single threaded program...but how to make sure there is no context switch happening, because other processes may also be running on VM
- Sometimes I get zero time taken, since I am measuring in nanoseconds, I find it strange, how something can execute in zero nanoseconds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am running tests in single threaded program...but how to make sure there is no context switch happening, because other processes may also be running on VM

Kill all processes that are not needed, and if you have an option, raise the priority of the profiled process.

Other then that, you can use [prof](http://www.unix.com/man-page/opensolaris/1/prof/) or [callgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html) to profile your program.

> Sometimes I get zero time taken, since I am measuring in nanoseconds, I find it strange, how something can execute in zero nanoseconds?

You are getting 0 ns execution time, because the CPU clock precision is above 10 ms.

Measure the time after more iterations, and you'll get better results.

---

Do more lookups, and then average the value :

```
 timespec start, end;
 clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
 for (int i=0;i<10000;++i)
 ---code--lookup in a unordered map <string, int>
 clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);
 int diff = diff_ns(end, start)/10000;
```

Like this time spent in clock_gettime will be neglected.

Comment: how can I calculate min / max if I do for every n number of iterations measurement.

Comment: @Medicine Do more lookups, and then average the value. If you do just one unordered map lookup, then do N instead, and divide the measured time by N - where N is some large number (10000+)